# Is my RCD Breaker faulty?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Every 2 weeks my main RCD trips and it wont reset. After an hour it will allow me to reset it and its fine for 2 weeks.

The main RCD has a short spur to another mini RCD board that was installed 10 years ago to power the extension. The Main breaker on this mini board trips but the individual lights/ring main RCDs on this mini board don't trip. This next circuit powers my kitchen which has integral fridge, freezer, cooker and dishwasher so I am unable to find the plugs to disconnect them but I'm thinking perhaps its not a faulty appliance as the individual ring main and lighting RCDs never trip just the main breaker to the extension.

Is my RCD faulty? I can't afford an electrician so I only want to get an electrician if its something I can't fix myself and most of the time there is no fault for them to assess.

Comment: RCD is also known as GFCI in the US: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device

Answer (score 3):

RCD will trip on a ground fault. Sometimes an older refrigerator or garbage disposal will cause them to trip.
Since it appears to have a cycle it may be a defrost setting in the refrigerator causing the fault.
It is possible the breaker itself is faulty but I would expect a more random tripping if this was the case.
Are there any other appliances that have a “cycle” if not try changing the temp in the refrigerator, colder might make it trip more often warmer less often if it is the defrost cycle.